# How to mock a full module?

Tags: unit-testing, perl, mocking

I have a module `B` that I want to test. This module depends on the module `A` that I don't want to test. Here is an example of my package `B`:

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

use A;

package B;
    
sub to_test {
    return A::a();
}
```

In my unit test, I would like to call `B::to_test` but I want to manually specify what value `A::a()` must return. To do that, I have written a module `MockA.pm` that contains all the subs of `A` to mock:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'FATAL' => 'all';

package Mock::A;

sub a {
    return "From mock";
}
    
1;
```

I know I can easily mock `A::a` using [`Test::MockModule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::MockModule), the problem is the package `A` may contain a lot of subs and `Test::MockModule` lets me mock them only one by one.

How can I mock the full `A` package with `MockA`?

Comment: Try Test::MockObject. Yes, it has a similar name to Test::MockModule, but it's a different idea. Both are useful and they can be used in conjunction with each other. But in your example, the real problem is the lack of dependency injection. Module B shouldn't blindly be calling `A::a()`. Instead, you should pass an object in to module B and module B should do `$object->a()`. That way you can provide a lightweight mock object instead of the real A object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existing answer shows how to replace parts of a module, which is quite sensible.

But if you wanted to replace the module entirely (to the point that the original doesn't even need to be installed), you can use the following:

```perl
# Use the name of the package we're mocking.
package A;

...

# Tell Perl that the module we're mocking has been loaded.
$INC{ ( __PACKAGE__ =~ s{::}{/}rg ) . '.pm' } = 1;
```

`use MockA;` must appear before any instances of `use A;`.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to redefine the subs defined in the package `A` by the subs in `MockA`. To do that, there are three conditions:

- `MockA` must define the same package than `A`;
- `MockA` must be included after all the inclusions of `A`;
- The warning `redefine` must not be fatal.

The file `MockA.pm` can be the following:

```
use strict;
# No fatal error if a sub is redefined
use warnings 'FATAL' => 'all', 'NONFATAL' => 'redefine';

# Override package A
package A;

sub a {
    return "From mock";
}
    
1;
```

And, in the unit test:

```
use B; # B includes A
use MockA; # MockA overrides A

B::to_test() # B calls MockA::a
```

Comment: You might want to look at Sub::Override too.

Comment: @simbabque I have taken a look to this module but I have not find any way to mock an entire package. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: No, that's just doing the same thing you are doing there, but with fewer `no strict`s. MockModule is fundamentally the same thing. You don't want to mock the whole thing though, do you? You want to run your code in B, and you want to inject dependencies for the calls to stuff in A for that particular all of B.

Comment: You've got the preconditions correct, too. You have to load the real thing first, or when it comes in it'll overwrite your changes.

Comment: On the other hand, is A doing something that involves external dependencies? Or does it provide access to branches in your code that you can only test by changing its return value?

Comment: @simbabque `A` is a wrapper to an external API. I would like to mock all the package the same way whatever the call of `B`.

Comment: Silencing the warnings (`no warnings qw( redefine );`) instead of making them nonfatal would make more sense

Comment: @ikegami I like the idea to have a message in my console to see there is a redefinition when I launch the unit test. But you are right, we may want to do that silently.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to want a message if the method *wasn't* redefined, since that's the unexpected condition. To each his own :)